# Centering a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, ios6, uikit

I am trying to center a UIImageView in a scroll view. Here is the code I tried with no results.

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kReceiptDetailScrollViewBackgroundCornered]];
[iv setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
[[self scrollView] insertSubview:iv atIndex:0];
```

Anybody know what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the image view's content mode to center, which means that the image is not scaled and it can be larger than the image view that displays it.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: kReceiptDetailScrollViewBackgroundCornered];
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
iv.frame = [self scrollView].bounds;
[[self scrollView] addSubview: iv];
```

Comment: The image is actually smaller than the scrollview, will this still work?

Comment: Yes, it will work. If you want the image to fill the whole scroll view, then try setting `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`.

Comment: The image still gets stretched when I try the above code, it's aspect now matches the aspect of the scrollview. I would like to maintain the image's existing aspect and set it in the middle of the scroll view.

Comment: Then just use UIViewContentModeCenter in the code I posted originally.